# reload state when you are on same state in angular ui-router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes, angular-ui-router, ngroute

My Question is can we reload the view in ui-router if you are on same state.
check my code at`http://plnkr.co/edit/MA7CuyH2RFrlaoAgBYog?p=preview

My app.js file is

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ui.router']);
app.config(function($stateProvider) {
$stateProvider
  .state("view1", {
    url: "/view1",
    templateUrl: "x.html"
  })
  .state("view2", {
    url: "/view2",
    templateUrl: "y.html"
  })
})
app.controller("MainCtrl",function(){});
```

And index page is

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
<a href="#/view1">Accounts</a>
<a href="#/view2">Dashboard</a>
<div ui-view></div>
```

Now click on **Dashboard** link here you will see a **text box**. fill any value in that. Now again click on **Dashboard** link. now the state should reload and all data of page should be reloaded including its controller. Please make sure to **ui-router** only.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21714655/angular-js-angular-ui-router-reloading-current-state-refresh-data

Comment: Hi Justin here the question is different. I want to reload the page with menu click if same menu is clicked

Answer (score 7, accepted):

add attribute to the element with

```
ui-sref=""ui-sref-opts="{reload:true}"
```

example:

```
<a ui-sref-opts="{reload:true}" ui-sref="app.post.applicants">Applicants</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use ng-click and write a controller function with $state.go

Answer (score 0):

You could catch the click in a "ng-click" and use the $state service to transition/reload pragmatically

Answer (score 0):

I had this similar issue and I solved this in two simple way ...

First I wrote a function into related controller (my state was 'inbox' you can use your own ui-state):

> `$scope.reload = function() {
>        $state.go('inbox', null, { reload: true }); 
>   }`

Second call this function to anchor tag:

> `<a ng-click="reload()">Inbox</a>`

Hope it will help. :)