# UI-Router state not changing as intended

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have an AngularJS app that uses UI-Router and has Authentication & Authorisation.

When changing $state I check authentication and authorisation and on failure I intend to redirect or request login.

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState) {
    var requiresAuth = toState.data.requiresAuth;
    if (requiresAuth) {
        var authorizedRoles = toState.data.authorizedRoles;
        if (!AuthService.isAuthorized(authorizedRoles)) {
            event.preventDefault();
            if (AuthService.isAuthenticated()) {
                // user is not allowed
                notifyError({ status: "Denied", statusText: "You don't have permission" });
            } else {
                // user is not logged in
                $rootScope.$broadcast(AUTH_EVENTS.notAuthenticated);
            }
            $rootScope.$state.go('app.dashboard');
        }
    }
});
```

My problem is that when on state 'app.dashboard' and attempting to navigate to a state on which I don't have permission or am not authenticated I see the state change (breadcrumbs change on view) but then the $stateChangeStart code above kicks in and should send the state back to 'app.dashboard' and it does...
I can debug and see the state is indeed changed back to app.dashboard but because the state already was 'app.dashboard' a reload doesn't take place therefore my navigation ui-sref-active directives don't update and the view (breadcrumbs) doesn't update.

```
<li data-ui-sref-active="active">
    <a data-ui-sref=" app.dashboard" title="Dashboard">
    <i class="fa fa-lg fa-fw fa-home"></i> <span class="menu-item-parent"> Dashboard</span>
    </a>
</li>
```

This all makes sense because AngularS is designed to prevent page reloads however I'm not sure how best to code around the problem.  I've taken advice and code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24928039/angular-ui-router-state-reentrance) and it works but I'm a little concerned about issues this could introduce as I further develop the application.

```
.config(function($provide) {
    $provide.decorator('$state', function($delegate)
    {
        $delegate.go = function(to, params, options)
        {
            return $delegate.transitionTo(to, params, angular.extend(
            {
                reload: true,
                inherit: true,
                relative: $delegate.$current
            }, options));
        };
        return $delegate;
    });
```

Ideally, I'd prefer to achieve what I want without changing the behaviour of UI-Router's $state provider.  Has anyone got any ideas?

Comment: Is there anything I can add to help get an answer?

Comment: Did you get a good solution for your problem? I have the same issue

Comment: No, unfortunately not.  I created an issue on github - https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/1818