# How to $state.go()

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Is my $stateProvider:

```
$stateProvider
.state('home', {
    url : '/',
    templateUrl : '/admindesktop/templates/main/',
    controller : 'AdminDesktopMainController'
}).state('company', {
    url : '/company',
    templateUrl : '/admindesktop/templates/grid/',
    controller : 'CompanyGridController'
}).state('company.detail', {
    url : '/{id:\d+}', //id is 
    templateUrl : '/admindesktop/templates/company/detail/',
    controller : 'CompanyDetailController'
});
```

It's work for 'company' state (I use ui-sref), but this code not work (called from 'company' state):

```
$state.go('.detail', {
    id: $scope.selectedItem.id //selectedItem and id is defined
});
```

I read official docs and answers from StackOverflow, but I don't found solution. I can't use ui-sref, I use ui-grid, and new state opened after select one row from table for editing.

What i do wrong?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

What would always work is the full state definition:

```
// instead of this
// $state.go('.detail', {
// use this
$state.go('company.detail', {
    id: $scope.selectedItem.id //selectedItem and id is defined
});
```

In [doc there are defined these options](https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/docs/0.3.1/index.html#/api/ui.router.state.$state#methods_go), but they depend on CURRENT state:

> **to**    *string*
>   Absolute state name or relative state path. Some examples:
>
> - $state.go('contact.detail') - will go to the contact.detail state
> - $state.go('^') - will go to a parent state
> - $state.go('^.sibling') - will go to a sibling state
> - $state.go('.child.grandchild') - will go to grandchild state

Comment: I tryed, it not working for me. Maybe, regular expression is wrong?

Comment: What you should use for having id int is this - `url: "/{id:int}",`. Here is working plunker for you: http://plnkr.co/edit/0EFN6S4LolaeuLHLFmxh?p=preview

Answer (score 2):

My error is in regular expression, really:

```
.state('company.detail', {
    url : '/{id:\d*}',
    templateUrl : '/admindesktop/templates/company/detail/',
    controller : 'CompanyDetailController'
 })
```

**{id:\d*}** worked (integer id).

Answer (score 2):

To load the current state. Check this out.

```
$state.go($state.current, {}, {reload: true}); //second parameter is for $stateParams
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23609343/1920574)