# pass object angular js $state.go

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to pass my object using $state.go method. my list date is

```
$scope.oldList = $stateParams.userDetailList;
```

when console above

```
console.log($scope.oldList)
```

data showed correctly. therefor no issue about the data.

now when I call go back function, I need to pass $scope.oldList data to the other page.
my goback function is as below. this function is in (sanction-screening-view page)

```
    $scope.goBack = function () {
    $state.go("app.sanction-screening");
  };
```

I need to pass my $scope.oldList object to the "app.sanction-screening" route. how i do it.

Comment: This question is duplicate to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28042598/how-to-state-go

Answer (score 0):

The go function can take two parameters:

```
$state.go('app.sanction-screening', $scope.oldList);
```