# How to make so a controller block is executed everytime a state is accessed?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angularjs-controller

I have a controller attached to a state, and everytime said state is accessed, I need my controller to run a block where I do a verification.

How can I do this?

Comment: make `reload: true` option inside state code

Comment: @pankajparkar but be defualt controller is refreshed isnt it?

Comment: @pankajparkar Oddly enough, this worked. I thought the controller always reloaded?

Comment: @pankajparkar add it an an answer

Comment: @ComicSansMSLover I added an answer

Comment: @A.B Thanks for appreciation dude:-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For reloading controller every time you should mention `reload: true` option on you `.state` declaration of ui-router

**Sample Code**

```
$stateProvider
.state('state1', {
      templateUrl: 'state1.html',
      controller: `state1Ctrl`,
      reload: true //forcefully reload route and load controller again
})
```

Also you could refer this [**SO Question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21714655/angular-js-angular-ui-router-reloading-current-state-refresh-data)

Comment: Can anyone confirm this works? I don't see it on UI Router docs (http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$stateProvider) and the reload it's not working for me.

Answer (score 1):

In order to call a particular function every time your location changes, you can also define the function in html as:

```
          <div ng-init="allDealerListing()">
```

So whenever the particular div in html is loaded the function is called automatically.

Hence upon change of state function is called

Answer (score 0):

controller do execute each time you can call an function for example init() function like below

```
.controller('test',function($scope){
  $scope.init = function( ){
  // your code block here
   }
  $scope.init();
 });
```

Comment: how does it will reload the controller?

Comment: @pankajparkar he says each time i state is accessed. controller code  gets executed when state is accessed

Comment: yeahh..obiviously controller code is also gets executed..looks like he want `resolve` function

Comment: he is not asking for state or controller reload i guess @pankajparkar

Comment: @pankajparkar may be :)