# AngularJS reinitialize controller

Tags: angularjs, routes, angular-ui-router, ionic-framework

I have got a controller named newGroupCtrl whose definition is like :

```
.state('new_group', {
    url: '/new_group',
    templateUrl: 'templates/new_group.html',
    controller: 'newGroupCtrl'
})

.controller('newGroupCtrl', function ($scope, $rootScope,$ionicHistory,$window) {
    $rootScope.roomId = $scope.getRoom();

    $scope.getRoom = function () {
        var date = new Date;
        var minutes = date.getMinutes();
        var hour = date.getHours();
        return 'room_' + hour + '' + minutes;
    };
}
```

I reach this contoller from previous page by :

```
$window.location.href = ('#/new_group');
```

That's good until now. `$rootScope.roomId` variable is initialized in the newGroupCtrl controller properly.

From this new_group page, I navigate to another page. And when I navigate back to this page by calling  `$window.location.href = ('#/new_group');`,
 `$rootScope.roomId` is not initialized again, instead its old value is still there. The state of the newGroupCtrl is preserved.

How can I completely reinitialize newGroupCtrl?

Comment: What does your getRoom() do? can you share its code details?

Comment: I added getRoom code as well

Comment: Since you're using ui-router, you should navigate with the $state service. $state.go('new_group');

Comment: Actually i'm not having this problem in my app. http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$state

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to tell `state` that reload controller each time when URL is getting accessed via browser by just adding adding `reload` option of state to `true` like `reload: true`.

**Code**

```
.state('new_group', {
    url: '/new_group',
    templateUrl: 'templates/new_group.html',
    controller: 'newGroupCtrl',
    reload: true //will reload controller when state is being access
});
```

You should use `$state.go('new_group')` instead of doing `$window.location.href = ('#/new_group');` which will ensure that the route changes will recognize by `ui-router`.

Same [**SO answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29355919/2435473) here

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using Ionic Framework (Good Job), you can do this:

```
.controller('YourCtrl', function($ionicView){
  $ionicView.enter(function(){
    //code that you want to run, each time the view is active
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the controller from :

```
.state('new_group', {
    url: '/new_group',
    templateUrl: 'templates/new_group.html',
})
```

And add the controller at "new_group.html" page with parent tag of the page like:

```
<div ng-controller="newGroupCtrl"></div>
```

Comment: this looks like hacky solution..:p

Answer (score 0):

Also I found helpful (for Ionic Framework) to use

```
.state('new_group', {
    url: '/new_group',
    templateUrl: 'templates/new_group.html',
    cache: false
})
```

Reference to similar question and problems:
[Reloading current state - refresh data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21714655/reloading-current-state-refresh-data) or in sjm's answer in [Reinitialize Controller every time when visiting View - Ionic Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31085034/reinitialize-controller-every-time-when-visiting-view-ionic-framework)