# Reinitialize Controller every time when visiting View - Ionic Framework

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, ionic-framework

Hi i'm having two views in my app with two controllers assigned to each.
Here i need to reinitialize the controller every time when ever i navigate to particular view.

Angular Script:

```
.state('app.pnrlist', {
            url: "/pnrlist",
            views: {
                'menuContent': {
                    templateUrl: "templates/test.html",
                    controller: "testControl",
                    reload: true
                }
            },
            reload:true
        })

        .state('app.home', {
            url: "/home",
            views: {
                'menuContent': {
                    templateUrl: "templates/home.html",
                    controller:"homeControl",
                    reload:true
                }
            },
            reload:true
        })
```

HTML Content

```
<ion-content>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item nav-clear menu-close href="#/app/home">
      Home
    </ion-item>
      <ion-item nav-clear menu-close href="#/app/pnrlist">
          PNR List
      </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

I have tried to implement many solutions on stack but none helped me.
[Solution Tried 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21714655/angular-js-angular-ui-router-reloading-current-state-refresh-data) / 
[Solution Tried 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30209527/angularjs-reinitialize-controller)

Comment: Check also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31073765/1679310) to get some idea about what we have with ionic

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If its a matter of the View not updating, disabling the Cache may help

i.e

```
.state('app.home', {
   url: "/home",
   cache: false,
```

As by default, views are cached to improve performance. You can also disable the cache via the 'cache-view' attribute

```
<ion-view cache-view="false" view-title="My Title!">
  ...
</ion-view>
```