# ionic framework redirection issue

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am having a redirection issue while using angular ionic framework. I have a list page displaying list of records, which has a add button. When user clicks on it, it takes to the add record screen, after user is done with adding record, i am trying to redirect it to the list page so that user can see newly added record.

Here is the code i am using for redirection. This does not work. It shows the correct url on the browser window, flips the view correctly but does not retrieve the newly inserted record. I tried to place a break point in my controller but my break point is not even being hit, while redirection.

```
$state.go('customer.detail', { 'id': key});
```

I also tried this but same result. It does not work either.
     $location.path("/detail/"+key);

Comment: Why are you using 'customer.detail'. What's your page url to which you wants to redirect? Is it customer or detail?

Comment: its the detail page. And syntax for $state.go is correct since i am not hard coding my urls in my controllers.It is alias defined in angular routing

Answer (score 1):

ok finally i was able to fix this issue by adding a property to my state as cache:false.

```
            .state('customer.detail', {
            url: '/detail/:cid',
            cache:false,
            views: {
                'tab-search': {
                    templateUrl: 'app/Customer/CustomerDetail.html'
                }
            }
        })
```

Got the tip here.

[Reloading current state - refresh data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21714655/angular-js-angular-ui-router-reloading-current-state-refresh-data)