# Submit button that redirects to another page with ui-router

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angularjs-ng-click

I am using AngularJS ui-router to go to different pages. I have a button that submits a form but I also want it to take me to a different page upon submission. So I tried to do something like this:

**Approach 1, button**

```
<button href="#anotherPage" type = "submit" ng-click = "someFunction()" class = "btn btn-default">Go to another page</button>
```

Typically, this is done in a link, so I also tried this:

**Approach 2, link**

```
<a href="#anotherPage" type = "submit" ng-click = "someFunction()" href="#results" class = "btn btn-default">Go to another page</a>
```

Approach 1 doesn't work because href doesn't work with buttons, approach 2 takes me to the other page but does not submit. What is the cleanest way to do this?

Comment: maybe this help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33460529/angularjs-and-reloading-and-redirect-after-submit-using-ui-router/33461052

Answer (score 3):

You can use `$state.go()` in your click method defined in your controller.

like -

Button Code -

```
<button ng-click="someFunction()" class="btn btn-default">Go to another page</button>
```

Method in controller -

```
$scope.someFunction = function() {
 // Process the data 
 $state.go('newsstate',{id: id});
};
```

Do not forget to inject `$state`.

As a suggestion- whenever you are using `ui-router` try to us `ui-sref` instead of simple `href`s.

Comment: what is the id field?

Comment: should I inject state into the function or the controller or both

Comment: @jebmarcus in your controller as a DI