# How to reset data of all the states : angularJs UI router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

```
.state('state1'
{
    name :
    url:
    data:{
      data1=[];
      data2=[];
     }

});

.state('state2'
{
    name :
    url:
    data:{
      data1=[];
      data2=[];
    }

});
```

Let us say I have n number of states.When user goes from one state to another
he is storing data into `$state.current.data`.

My question is , "is there any shortcut or any technique to reset the data for all the states again", let us say for the scenario when user logs out from the application , I want to reset the data .

**I don't want to use $window.location.reload()**

Any suggestions/help is appreciated!!

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reloading current state - refresh data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21714655/reloading-current-state-refresh-data)

Comment: for me $state.go($state.current, {}, {reload: true}); does not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [$state.get()](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#stategetstatename) to get all the configured states and then reinitialize the `data` object to a desired value.

**Important:** child states inherit the `data` property from their parent states - [source](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-%26-Nested-Views#what-do-child-states-inherit-from-parent-states). In order not to break the inheritance we'll use [angular.copy](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy).

#### This example reinitializes the `data` object with `{}`

```
angular.forEach($state.get(), function (state) {
  angular.copy({}, state.data);
});
```

Note that there isn't any way to know the original value of the `data` object without explicitly specifying or storing it.

Comment: Thank you. But I canot use angular.copy() simply because, next time when user get logs in into the application , will get error like cannot read data1, data2 of undefined, it is because I am not refreshing/reloading the page.So instead of this I have to individually check if(state.data.data1 && state.data.data1.length>0){stata.data.data1=[]}