# Angular navigate to the previous state on page reload

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I wanted to know if there is a way in Angular to refresh a single page application and properly go back to the same state as before? I am using `ui-router` (version 0.2.15) for defining different states.

Currently, I am storing the state name using `ngStorage` and have placed `$state.go(last_stored_state_name)` in the controller of the state that loads first. This way I get to the state that i was on before refresh but the problem is i can see the first state's view just for a second before `$state.go(last_stored_state_name)` runs.

Can anyone please tell me how I can bypass the first state's view directly to the desired state?

Comment: dependening on the version of ui-router you'll have the reload parameter available to you. http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$state what version of ui-router are you using?

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21714655/reloading-current-state-refresh-data]

Comment: I am using version 0.2.15

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$state.go($state.current, {}, {reload: true});
```

Comment: Do i add this in the controller of every state?

Answer (score 0):

Create a controller and add it with `ng-controller` at any top level element like on `<body>` tag so that its scope is available throughout the application and in that controller, do like this:

```
// Event listener for state change.
$scope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState) {
    if (last_stored_state_name && isPageRefresh) {
        // prevent execution of current state and navigate to last saved state
        event.preventDefault();
        $state.go(last_stored_state_name);
        return;
    }
});
```

So you don't have to do `$state.go(last_stored_state_name);` in your controller. This way, you will not see the first state for a second.

You can figure out a variable `isPageRefresh` with any type of checks like checking if `fromState` is null or setting a local storage variable or setting a global javascript variable .

Comment: I have actually done something similar to this. I have captured the refresh event using  windowElement.on('beforeunload', function (event) {}) and have set the storage variables inside it. This i have done in every controller so that refresh from anyone will trigger the saving of state. The problem lies after this when the view loads.

Comment: I tried your answer. I detected the refresh event in the state using my earlier approach and added your approach in a top level controller to change the state after reload. It still is not working. Moreover, the $state.go() in your approach is not getting executed.