# AngularJS load data on state load

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a page in my Angular.js app that does a http request and fills in some textboxes with the results.

I navigate to this page by using :

```
$state.go('utab.history');
```

but when it gets to the page all the textboxes are blank, i am currently using Ionics ion refresher :

```
<ion-refresher
    pulling-text="Pull to refresh..."
    on-refresh="showappraisal()">
</ion-refresher>
```

to call the controllers function which then populates all the textboxes, but now the apps nearly done i need to solve this issue.

I have tried using `$rootScope.$emit("CallParentMethod", {});` just before  `$state.go('utab.history');` and it does run the function but again, it just doesnt populate the textboxes until i do the pull refresh (even though they call the same function).

Is there a way to get an event when utab.history loads?

Comment: i think we need some more code to resolve this.  Like how do you load your data exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a listener function in your view controller, and make changes whatever you want.

```
app.controller("yourcontroller", ['$scope', '$ionicView', function($scope, $ionicView){

    $scope.$on('$ionicView.afterEnter', function(e){
        //You can call your functions
    });

});
```

or

```
app.controller("yourcontroller", ['$scope', '$ionicView', function($scope, $ionicView){

    $scope.init = function(){
        $scope.$on('$ionicView.afterEnter', function(e){
            //You can call your functions
        });
   }

$scope.init(); //initialize by your own

});
```

There are so many events are available while navigating from one view to another.

**Available Events:**
   loaded, enter, leave, beforeEnter, beforeLeave, afterEnter, afterLeave, unloaded.

You can listen any of the above events for your convenience.

**Refernce** : http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionView/

Answer (score 0):

I believe your question is a little bit vague. But if I understand it correctly you can do this:

You can send a data to a state by

```
$state.go('myView', { myKey: myData });
```

And access the data from

```
$stateParams.myKey
```

Additionally, don't get trigger the get request event with any events, you can use `$ionicView.beforeEnter` event to understand when the page is loaded (even though there exist cache in Ionic in default)

Comment: I dont want to send data, when i do $state.go('utab.history'); i want to be able to run a function in that controller. currently if that state was already open it does nothing just takes you to the page.

Comment: Okay then, `$ionicView.beforeEnter` will be called everytime the page is loaded even though there is a cache.

Comment: thats exactly what i was looking for thanks very much

Comment: Not a problem. Please accept my answer in StackOverflow for the sake of the community :)

Answer (score 0):

```
 $scope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
      if(toState == 'utab.history')
      {
          // do your stuff
      }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check this out. It worked for me.

```
$state.go($state.current, {}, {reload: true}); //second parameter is for $stateParams
```

Documentation: https://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$state#methods_reload

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23609343/1920574)

Answer (score -1):

You can call `showappraisal()` in your controller's constructor:

```
angular.controller('myId', function(){

  this.showappraisal = function() {
    //logic to load data here
  };

  //this will do the call when the controller is created which should happen when the state is started
  this.showappraisal();

});
```

Comment: Are you referring to the html page or the state?

Comment: Then why you define a function? In that case you can write the code directly in the controller.

Comment: The code is put into a function because it can be called by `ion-refresher` to refresh the data on demand from the user.