# Trying to hard reload page with Ui router, works on chrome, but not working on safari and firefox

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I use ui-roter for my app. I want my page to reload itself when I send a `hardRelad` parameter.

This is how I go to that state.

```
$state.go("widget", {"widgetUrl" : url, "hardReload": true});
```

This is my controller, where I reload when parameter is passed.

This works fine in chrome, but doesn't work on safari and chrome. It reloads home state which is `localhost:8080/#`

```
(function(){

  'use strict'

  angular
    .module('myApp')
    .controller('WidgetController', controllerFunction)
  controllerFunction.$inject = ['$window', '$stateParams', '$scope'];

  function controllerFunction($window, $stateParams, $scope) {
    var vm = this;
    $scope.widgetUrl = $stateParams.widgetUrl;
    if($stateParams.hardReload) {
      $window.location.reload();
    }
  }
})();
```

This is my routing definition

```
$stateProvider
  .state('home', {
    url: '/',
    templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
    controller: 'MainCtrl as vm'
  })
  .state('widget', {
    url: '/widget/{widgetUrl}',
    params: {
      hardReload: false
    },
    templateUrl: 'views/widget.html',
    controller: 'WidgetController as vm'
  });
```

Comment: I also tried $stateChangeSuccess and $viewContentLoaded events, but these events are fired before url change. If there is an event after url change, it might help too

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21714655/reloading-current-state-refresh-data

Comment: @MuliYulzary I already tried this one, it doesnt load all page, I need my third party libraries to reload too

Comment: have you tried `$location.reload()`?

Answer (score 0):

I used `$locationChangeSuccess` this worked. Thanks for your help

```
$rootScope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess',
  function (event) {
    if(event.currentScope.hardReload) {
      $window.location.reload();
    }
  });
```