# passing parameters to state is causing element to not show

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, angular-ui-router

In my AngularJS App, I have a form in which the user needs to enter an application number, and if successful, display content below which displays appropriate data. This data I can only access through the `scope` if I pass it as a parameter to the current `state`. I am using `ui-router` for routing.

I have read threads such as [Reloading current state - refresh data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21714655/reloading-current-state-refresh-data) which has advised me that I can pass data to the current state and not refresh the page but it keeps refreshing and the content doesn't show. I am also not sure whether I am using `ng-show` and/or `ng-if` correctly. My function to pass the data is as follows:

```
vm.findPatent = function(patentNo) {
    searchPatentService.findPatent(patentNo)
    .then(
        function(data) {
            $state.go('.', { patent: data }, {reload: false, notify: false, location: false})
            })
        },
        function(errResponse) {
            console.error('Error while finding patent');
        }
    );
}
```

And my parameters within the `state`:

```
.state('search-patent', {
    url: '/search-patent',
    component: 'searchpatent',
    params: {
        navigation: 'patentnav',
        patent: null
    }
})
```

And my view with the form which displays the content below on form submit:

```
<form ng-submit="$ctrl.findPatent(searchPatent)" name="searchPatentForm">
    <fieldset>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <labelfor="searchPatent">EP No.</label>
            <div>
                <input type="text" name="searchPatent" ng-model="searchPatent" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" required>
            </div>
        <div>
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</form> 

<div class="row" ng-show="searchPatentForm.$submitted">
    <div class="col-md-12">
//ANOTHER FORM AND CONTENT WHICH IS DISPLAYED ON SUBMIT
    </div>
</div>
```

***Question***

How do I pass the data to the current `state` without refreshing the page? Also, is there a better solution to using `ng-show`? Thanks

Comment: still not clear whats your goal ? you want to refresh page onClick ??and show some data ??

Comment: Why you are not willing to use $scope ??

Comment: Apologies. So on submit, I need to pass parameters to the current state and remaind on the current state and page, so I can display the necessary object properties, in the container that displays (through ng-show) on submit. The issue I have is that it the parameters are passed but the page refreshes and the containe that is meant to show, flashes for a second and then disappears

Comment: I do, I use `vm` instead and `$ctrl` in the view, but if you have an example that could help me, it would be greatly appreciated

Comment: See my answer this should work @Patrick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want to remain on the page after you have submitted .

```
$scope.result= null;
vm.findPatent = function(patentNo) {
    searchPatentService.findPatent(patentNo)
    .then(
        function(data) {
            $scope.result=data;
            })
        },
        function(errResponse) {
            console.error('Error while finding patent');
        }
    );
}
```

In your view you should use `ng-if` if you want your div to be recreated else use `ng-show` [see details here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21869283/when-to-favor-ng-if-vs-ng-show-ng-hide)

```
<div class="row" ng-if="result">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      {{result}}
    </div>
</div>
```

For detailed example see [here](https://github.com/noman57/login)

Comment: Ahhh brilliant, lot simpler. Though only issue is the container is showing before the initial form submit? How do I hide it before the user clicks submit?

Comment: Sorted it. Addded `&& searchPatentForm.$submitted`. Thank you for your time @Abdullah

Comment: Np You can only use the '$scope.result.length'

Comment: What do you mean sorry?